# Can other Heroes and/or Monsters be purchased separately for Castle Ravenloft?

Tags: dnd-adventure-system, castle-ravenloft

Can I purchase additional monsters or heroes for the CR board game?  And if so, do they come with their stat cards?  Just want to get the most out of the game as possible.

Answer (score 5):

A [Gray Hag](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/80591/castle-ravenloft-gray-hag-promo) promo exists, but it was a fairly limited release.

[Wrath of Ashardalon](http://wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/214420000) is fully compatible with Castle Ravenloft, and Wizards has released [bonus adventures](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20110408) that combine the two games.

[Legend of Drizzt](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/355940000) is the latest game in the series and, according to the product information page, is also fully compatible with both other games.

Comment: Still a valid answer but links are dead, just fyi

Comment: Except for gray hag

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about add-ons for Castle Ravenloft, but I know wizards made ANOTHER D&D Adventure System board game called [Wrath of Ashardalon](http://wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/214420000).